# Don't count visitors who go to a certain link using Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to make sense of the Google Analytics on my company site. Many of our employees will be visiting the site just to click on the timesheet link, and I want to remove these users from my stats.

The issue is that the link is within the site's domain, but is a separate system (not part of the main site's CMS) and so doesn't have the analtyics tracking code in its pages.

Visits to this page aren't picked up by Google Analytics as there is no tracking code, and the page isn't seen as an external link as its within the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no tracking code analytics will not see anything and will not count it. Fact of it being under main domain doesn't change anything.

No tracking code = Doesn't exist for Ganalytics.

Comment: But if the link was external, then I believe I would be able to remove all visitors that left via that link from my results. Correct me if im wrong.... Thanks

Comment: @jdln wait I think I understood your question. Easiest thing to do would be to exclude all traffic from your company from the results. Simply exclude range of IP's from your workplace, more here: http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55572 This way analytic will not count visits of employees.

Comment: We have remote employees all over the country so it wont be reliable to manually exclude IPs or get them to download a special cookie (the other normal solution to this problem). Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid cookie/ipblock are your only options. I don't think you can first register visit and than remove it from the total count post factum when visitor clicks certain link.

Comment: @user793011 Why don't you make a subdomain for time-sheet and ask company employees to use that? like time.domain.com so they stop passing through homepage wasting traffic and registering useless visits?

Comment: Ill ask but although it should be, im not sure thats achievable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google URL builder tool to set the link as a campaign.
Ref: http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=55578

Next, use the 'Advanced segments' to filter campaign out from the Analytics data using the Exclude option, campaign and containing = campaign name.

That should give you all the data except with link related data excluded.

Comment: What do you mean? Isnt that tool for creating a new url within my site? If so, how will that help? Thanks

Comment: If I start filling in the fields what should I put for Campaign Source and Campaign Medium?

Comment: The tool is used to track campaigns e.g. if you send a newsletter in July 2012 with links to your site page, you set campaign as 'july 2012 newsletter' and medium as 'email'. This shows up under campaigns in your analytics if users click and arrive at your site.

Comment: You can choose the name, source and medium e.g. employees, office, internet and then filter the 'employees' campaign in Advanced Segments

Comment: Right, sorry but how does that help me? Employees are arriving at my site (mainly directly or by googeling the company name) and then clicking the timesheet link.

Comment: If they don't click the link to timesheet, then this method will miss those numbers.

Comment: Sorry for the hand holding, but can you give me step by step instructions or explain the concept as I dont get it at all. I thought that that tool was to generate urls so you could send users to mysite.com/newpage, and you could then track what those users do. I cant control the url of the timesheet link. I also dont think GA knows when users have clicked the timesheet link as its destination page doenst have the tracking code. Thanks

Comment: If i try and set up a goal, and the goal is for users to visit a url, the autocomplete knows all the pages in my site except for the timesheet page.

Comment: @user793011 As I said:  I don't think you can first register visit and than remove it from the total count post factum when visitor clicks certain link.
Trick explained by Ravi works the other way around, users arrive from pre-defined link and you know this before and you don't add them to total count.

Comment: This my understanding, thats why I was asking @Ravi to explain things.

Comment: @user793011 My understanding was source gets replaced by utm_source when user clicks, destination page lacking GA probably rules that out though.